# Mysql set two fields keep the same value?

Tags: mysql

Like below, I hope I can connect id:1,2value and id:1,3value
If I modify one of connected field and the other value keep the same with new value
How can i do it?

ID VALUE
1 __ 10
2 __ 10
3 __ 50
4 __ 50

---

After I modify id==1,value=15

ID VALUE
1 __ 15
2 __ 15
3 __ 50
4 __ 50

---

Then after I modify id==4,value=100

ID VALUE
1 __ 15
2 __ 15
3 __ 100
4 __ 100

Comment: Why do you want/need to do that ? What is the original requirement ?

Comment: in a sell store project, there are a same equipment for many products. The current structure is that each products can setting each equiptment  amount, but I hope that I can connect it and without modify the project php file

Comment: I Hope there is a way just like C point, that can let me to just modify one value but the another value will be change,too

Comment: I really don't think you can set up such a system. Maybe through a trigger, but I don't think it's a great idea. I would refactor the DB and code to add a  new level of hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate answer to your question is to use a `where` clause in an update:

```
update table t cross join
       (select t.* from table t where id = XXX) tt
       on t.value = tt.value
    set t.value = 15;
```

By changing the XXX in the subquery, you can do the update on rows with matching values.

The more complex answer to your question is to use a trigger to maintain this relationship.

The right answer to your question is to fix the data structure.  It sounds like you are storing different levels of information in the same table.  Instead, you need to tables.  Something like this:

Your table now becomes:

```
id     table1Id
 1         1
 2         1
 3         2
 4         2
```

Table1 has:

```
id      Value
 1        10
 2        50
```

Then, you do your update to `table1` not to your table.  This would be more properly normalized.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't tell enough info. I need to modify one project code, so I hope do not modify php file. So I hope there is a way that only connect the field just like C program point.